# How can I secure internal roles in azure (SSL at minimum)

Tags: ssl, azure, internal, role, worker

I am working on a HIPAA cloud project and am implementing a Key Store as a central repository for all of the key pairs for PHI(Private Health Information) encryption... I am not worried about the actual data because it will be encrypted at rest and in transit.

However when a worker or webrole needs to work with the data they need to decrypt and reencrypt it (if they do updates).  That's where the key Store comes into play.  However, I don't want this internal service exposed and I also need it to be SSLed, because sending keys in the clear, even inside a virtual network of roles wouldn't pass a security audit.

So any suggestions on how I can get a web or worker role to use SSL with an internal endpoint?

Thanks

Comment: I am not an attorney and this is not meant as legal advice.  From my reading of HIPPA is if it is a closed network (public does not have physical access) then it does not need to be encrypted.  You could argue the internal endpoints are a closed network.  Not sure you would win that argument.

Comment: I would agree except the shared nature of a cloud solution means that we can't assume our "internal" network is secure like we can in a physical network where we can trace the wires and show physical access security to the facility.

Comment: Been a while since read the statute. If the wording is "internal" then that is way different than "closed" and I agree.   I don't mean to detract from a great question but then even storing the keys in the cloud comes into question.

Comment: So, maybe it's better for you to use input endpoints, which can be secured with https? They may be less secure than internal ones, but the security would at least be demonstrable? Either that or 'HIPAA cloud project' becomes a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. Internal endpoints are on a closed network branch, so https would normally be redundant (although I understand your compliance issues). I found this answer (to my question) very useful in figuring out the security of internal endpoints: [How secure are Windows Azure internal endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584163/how-secure-are-windows-azure-internal-endpoints) - see the more detailed post that Brent links to.