# How to enable SSL communication for inter-role communication in azure

Tags: azure, ssl

I have a web service deployed in azure having a single web role and multiple worker roles. I can connect to web role using HTTPS but the inter-role communication over nettcp remains insecure. I want to enable the ssl based inter-role communication. Any pointer please?

Comment: Found some useful links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg465718.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557552.aspx,   But still not sure if it is possible to bind a certificate with an internal endpoint.

Comment: Another linked post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061198/how-can-i-secure-internal-roles-in-azure-ssl-at-minimum