# Azure - secure communication between internal roles in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

In this link ([Azure: security between web roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820368/azure-security-between-web-roles)) the OP asks: "In Azure, if you choose to use internal endpoint (instead of input endpoint), https is not an option. http & tcp are the only options. Does it mean internal endpoint is 100% secure and you don't need encryption"

the answer he gets is: No, a web/worker role cannot connect to an internal endpoint in another deployment

My question is possible at all to deploy such a solution?

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate things you brought up in your question.

1. Internal endpoints are secure in that the only other VM instances that can access these are within the same deployment. If, say, a web app needs to talk to a WCF service on a worker role instance, it can direct-connect with a tcp or http connection, with no need for encryption. It's secure.
2. Communication between deployments requires a Virtual Network, as internal endpoints are not accessible outside the boundary of the deployment. You can connect two deployments via Virtual Network, and a that point each of the virtual machine instances in each deployment may see each other. The notion of endpoints is moot at this point, as you can simply connect to a specific port on one of the server instances.